# How to insert text anchor inside script tag onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to insert TEXT ANCHOR 1 as a part of the src value inside script tag? I will use this on a tabbed content. Thank you. [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9uguotcg/3/).

```
<a href="#">TEXT ANCHOR 1</a>

<div class='tab'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/TEXT ANCHOR 1 WILL GO HERE?max-results=5&amp;alt=json-in-script"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you actually want?? I have updated the fiddle since the script was not included properly.

Comment: thanks! On my fiddle, the title "CATEGORY 1" is to be a part of the javascript inside tab1. and so on...

Comment: ok .. so it helped actually right??

Comment: you need to add the anchor tag on anchor tag ?

Comment: maybe my explanation is not clear... I updated the fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/9uguotcg/3/

Comment: you need to replace the content of text anchor ?

Comment: I have a javascript with a missing part as you can see it in the fiddle. ( [-----------------] ). Either on page load or onclick, the missing part should be replaced using  the text anchor of li.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9uguotcg/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
$('ul.tabmenu li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tabmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // -- Added --
    // Grab the tab text and trim any spaces
    var tab_text = $.trim($(this).text());
    // Find the script tag
    var $script = $('#' + tab_id).find("script");
    // Replace anything b/w /-/ and ? with the tab text
    $script.attr("src", $script.attr("src").replace(/\/-\/.*?\?/gi, "/-/" + tab_text + "?"));
    // -- End --

    $('#' + tab_id).fadeIn('slow').addClass('active');
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/9uguotcg/6/)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work :) <script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/TO-BE-REPLACED?max-results=5"></script>  the text TO-BE-REPLACED or between  / and ? should be replaced by the text anchor of the li.

Comment: It DOES work in the fiddle I posted, but only when you click on the tabs. Did you want it to work on load as well?

Comment: Yup maybe we can try the onload aswell.

Comment: Then replace the last `});` with `}).click();`

Comment: I checked it with Inspect Element and I can see it working. Maybe blogger just don't support it. thanks:)